# Always show trailing zeros in bc

Tags: unix, bc

How to show trailing zeros in integer or how to convert it to float in bc?
I know about `scale`, but it works only with floats:

```
$ echo "scale=3; 3/2" | bc
1.500
$ echo "scale=3; 1+1" | bc
2
```

I want to get result seems like `2.000`. I guess it's not difficult to do it with sed, but I'm a novice at this.

Comment: you could pipe the  output of `bc` to `printf`: `echo "scale=3; 1+1" | bc | xargs printf "%.3f\n"`. (the xargs seems to be necessary, I can't figure out how to pipe directly into printf).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo "scale=3; $1+$2" | bc | sed 's/^[0-9]*$/&\.000/g'
```

It works fine for me:

```
$ echo "scale=3; 3/2" | bc | sed 's/^[0-9]*$/&\.000/g'
1.500
$ echo "scale=3; 3+2" | bc | sed 's/^[0-9]*$/&\.000/g'
5.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1 to convert to a number with fractional part:

```
$ echo "scale=3; 1+1/1" | bc
2.000
```

once a divide of any kind has been done, if that value ends up being part of the output, it will be printed with the specified number of digits.

They're not "floats" in bc -- they're "fixed-point" -- numbers with a fixed number of digits after the decimal point.  Internally, they're just integers divided by a fixed power of 10 (set by the `scale` command)

Comment: It doesn't work when result is 0: `$ echo "scale=3; 1-1/1" | bc`